# fleqn not left aligning two equations

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I've looked at multiple similar queries but can't find a question with this specific issue. I've set the document class to `fleqn` which worked for other equations in my document, but not for equations 21 & 22 (see the image and code below).

I tried modifying the parameters to amsmath with `fleqn` which has the same effect. Also tried using `\begin{equation} \end{equation}` with no luck.

[image: equation image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{llncs}
...
\begin{align}
SC1 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{j \in J}} x_{kjw} + s_{jkw}^{1} - s_{jkw}^{2} = d_{zjkw} ~~ \forall z \in Z, j \in J, k \in K, w \in W \\
SC2 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} x_{kjwz_1} + s_{zjkw}^{3} - s_{zjkw}^{4} = 1 \\
SC3 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} x_{kjwZ} + s_{zjkw}^{5} - s_{zjkw}^{6} = 1 \\
SC4 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} [x_{ijkw} + x_{i(j+1)kw}] + s_{ijw}^{7} - s_{ijw}^{8} = 0,~ \forall i \in I, j \in J, w \in W
\end{align}
```

Comment: you don't have any alignment points (`&`)  specified in your alignment (normally just before the `=`) also why the `\mathlarger` which gives the expression a rather odd appearance as it's just round the summation?

Comment: That's it fixed now - thanks! https://imgur.com/x71f82D

Simply put more senior researchers in my field have their equations in that fashion and I want to follow suit. Thanks for your assistance, David!

Please put this as an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: the summations still look like a poke in the eye set with `\mathlarger` but I removed that comment from the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any alignment points (`&`) specified in your alignment (normally just before the =)

Answer (score 0):

For left alignment you need an alignment point, but in this case you can use `gather`, because there is no really good alignment point except the far left of all formulas.

Instead of the amazing `\mathlarger{\sum\limits_{j\in J}}` it's better to have a proper definition (so you can later redefine `\lsum` to be just `\sum`).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{llncs}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lsum}{\DOTSB\mathop{\mathlarger{\sum}}\slimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Ugly}
\begin{align}
SC1 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{j \in J}} x_{kjw} + s_{jkw}^{1} - s_{jkw}^{2} = d_{zjkw} ~~ \forall z \in Z, j \in J, k \in K, w \in W \\
SC2 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} x_{kjwz_1} + s_{zjkw}^{3} - s_{zjkw}^{4} = 1 \\
SC3 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} x_{kjwZ} + s_{zjkw}^{5} - s_{zjkw}^{6} = 1 \\
SC4 \mathlarger{\sum\limits_{k \in K}} [x_{ijkw} + x_{i(j+1)kw}] + s_{ijw}^{7} - s_{ijw}^{8} = 0,~ \forall i \in I, j \in J, w \in W
\end{align}

\paragraph{Bad}
\begin{gather}
\text{SC1}\,
  \lsum_{j \in J} x_{kjw} + s_{jkw}^{1} - s_{jkw}^{2} = d_{zjkw}
  \quad \forall z \in Z, j \in J, k \in K, w \in W \\
\text{SC2}\,
  \lsum_{k \in K} x_{kjwz_1} + s_{zjkw}^{3} - s_{zjkw}^{4} = 1 \\
\text{SC3}\,
  \lsum_{k \in K} x_{kjwZ} + s_{zjkw}^{5} - s_{zjkw}^{6} = 1 \\
\text{SC4}\,
  \lsum_{k \in K} [x_{ijkw} + x_{i(j+1)kw}] + s_{ijw}^{7} - s_{ijw}^{8} = 0,
  \quad \forall i \in I, j \in J, w \in W
\end{gather}

\paragraph{Good}
\begin{gather}
\text{SC1}\,
  \sum_{j \in J} x_{kjw} + s_{jkw}^{1} - s_{jkw}^{2} = d_{zjkw}
  \quad \forall z \in Z, j \in J, k \in K, w \in W \\
\text{SC2}\,
  \sum_{k \in K} x_{kjwz_1} + s_{zjkw}^{3} - s_{zjkw}^{4} = 1 \\
\text{SC3}\,
  \sum_{k \in K} x_{kjwZ} + s_{zjkw}^{5} - s_{zjkw}^{6} = 1 \\
\text{SC4}\,
  \sum_{k \in K} [x_{ijkw} + x_{i(j+1)kw}] + s_{ijw}^{7} - s_{ijw}^{8} = 0,
  \quad \forall i \in I, j \in J, w \in W
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]